# Android Studio, FileWriter not creating

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use `FileWrite` to write sensor data of the phone. But I could the get the basic generating new `FileWriter` working. It seems to return null. Here is the code, basically it tries to create a writer when a button is clicked then just write a few lines of 'hi'. But the program catches the exception at `writer = new FileWriter(destPath, true);` and Writer unsuccess. is toasted. Any idea why this error happens?

```
package com.example.jiajunyang.bowdetection;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.hardware.Sensor;
    import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
    import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
    import android.hardware.SensorManager;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener

    {

        private static final String destPath = "mySensorData.txt";

        FileWriter writer;

        // Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
        static {
            System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            File sdCardFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + " \filename.txt");

            Log.d("TAG", sdCardFile.getPath());
        }

        public void onStartClick(View view) {

            try {

                writer = new FileWriter(destPath, true);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start writer. ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                writer.write("hi \n");
                writer.write("hi \n");
                writer.write("hi \n");

                writer.flush();
                writer.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Writer unsuccess. ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wich exception is catched?

Comment: `and Writer unsuccess. is toasted`. You should alo toast `e.getMessage()` so the user of your app sees the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I develop Mobile Applications with Java.

Some Java APIs just don't work with Android. Are you sure FileWriter does?

Also, the way you define your destination path seems a little bit odd to me.

Here is an Android code example:

```
String filename = "myfile";
String string = "Hello world!";
FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
  outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
  outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can find more details [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html#java).

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't return any error nor crashed. But it seems the file is not stored for some reason. I also try to make a new directory at such as "/sdcard/file.txt" but I have permission denied. I have given the user-permission to android for writing to external device. Internal also doesn't work. I used the search function on file explorer, the file doesn't seem to exist even though outputStream ran without any exception. :(